# Check if List<string> contains any value besides specified

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I need to check if a List contains any values outside of 3 specified.

Example:
I have this  `var sourceList = new List<string>("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");` and I want to check that list contains any value BESIDES "E", "F", "G".  Just a Bool is fine and `sourceList` is a dynamic subset of a predefined list that the User would have selected.  My BESIDES List would be static.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var flag = sourceList.Except(new[] { "E", "F", "G" }).Any();
```

Answer (score 5):

Using LINQ:

```
bool contains = sourceList.Any(t => (t != "E" && t != "F" && t != "G"));
```

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, just updated after understanding that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

User `Except` and `Any` extensions to accomplish your goal:

```
var sourceList = new List<string>{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
var c = sourceList.Except( new List<string>{ "E", "F", "G"}).Any();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var sourceList = new List<string>("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
var checkList = new List<string>("E", "F", "G");
bool anyBesides = sourceList.Except(checkList).Any();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is less desirable to create a new list with `Except` and the current `Any` solution cannot be reused for different combinations of letters.

A combination of [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx) and [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) should suffice.

```
var sourceList = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
var except = new[] { "E", "F", "G" };

var containsExcept = sourceList.Any(x => except.Contains(x));
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why it's "less desirable".  Not disagreeing or agreeing but just genuinely curious about how to do things the "best" way.

Comment: `Except` produces the set difference between two lists. This is fine for what you want to do, but consider the performance implications of creating a new list just to throw it out with the `Any` extension method. However, it could be considered premature optimization to think that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sourceList = new List<string>{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};

 bool res =sourceList.SequenceEqual(new string[] { "A", "B", "C"});
```

Also don't forget there is no constructor such you have written:

`var sourceList = new List<string>("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");`

It should be:

```
var sourceList = new List<string>{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sourceList = new List<string>{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
var besidesList = new List<string>{"E", "F", "G"};  
var anyBesides = sourceList.Any(t => !besidesList.Contains(t));
```